# For loop with condition in R

Tags: r

Im new at programing in R.

I have a list which contains numbers between 0 and 5.  I want to count how many times 1 appears before 5, in result2 stored my list. I have done this:

```
counting<-function(lista,n,m){
p=2
 for (p in data_list){
 if(results2[p]==n && results2[p-1]==m){
  length(p)
  }
 p<-p+1
 }   
}
counting(results2,5,1)
```

Can anyone please provide me with som helpful adivce to imporve my code since it does not work.

Comment: Just a tip: try to keep the indentations in your code for it to be more clear for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We loop over the `list`, find the index of the first 5, get the sequence (`seq`), use that to subset the `list` element and count the number of 1 by creating a logical expression with `==` and using `sum` on that

```
sapply(data_list, function(x) {
       i1 <-  which(x == 5)
       i2 <- i1[i1 > 1]
       if(length(i2) > 0) {
          sum(x[i2-1] == 1)
   } else NA_real_
    })
#[1] 3 3
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`, we can make use of `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dbl(data_list, ~ sum(.x == 5 & lag(.x) == 1, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 3 3
```

#### data

```
data_list <- list(c(3,4,1,5 ,2,3,1,5,4,1,5), 
      c(3,4,1,5 ,2,3,1,5,4,1,5))
```

Comment: it says :Error in seq.default(match(5, x)) : 'from' must be a finite number

Comment: @Abbe can you try now

Comment: Error: unexpected ')' in:
"          sum(x[seq(i1)] == 1)
   })"

Comment: @Abbe sorry, i forgot to close the `}`.  can you check now

Comment: Hm the output is just a list with all 0 and all other numbers is substituted with 'NA'

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. if the list is( 3,4,1,5 ,2,3,1,5,4,1,5)  then 1 appears before 5 three times! It  is supposed to compare with the previous index

Comment: @Abbe Can you show a small reproducible example to test

Comment: @Abbe I read your question as the number of 1s before the first 5.

Comment: @Abbe Now, you can you test

Comment: Just NA all over the list, hmmm

Comment: @Abbe based on your example, the updated function now gets 3

Comment: still just NA, am I just supposed to run the code or change anything?

Comment: @Abbe I showed a reproducible example with `data` in my post.  It is not giving any NA.  That data is base don what you showed as input

Comment: @akrun - does base R have a function similar to "partition" in Clojure? That would make this a lot easier.

Comment: @BillO'Brien I am not familiar with `Clojure`

Comment: partition(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 1) would return list(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(3,4)). The 2nd and 3rd parameters are length and step size. It would be useful for problems like this.